# Bound state of Hydrogen atom at large $r$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

When the radial equation of SE is solved for Hydrogen atom, to see the asymptotic behavior, we assume $r$ tends to infinity.
The differential equation we are left with is:

$$
d^2U/dr^2 = -\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}
$$
where $U = R(r)/r$.
If we assume $E$ to be positive, we get an oscillating term which is reasonable. But if we assume $E$ to be negative, we get an exponentially decaying term which I don't get. Here we've ignored the potential so what is $E$ negative relative to? How could the wave function possibly decay radially, if we are considering a region where potential is negligible and essentially free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no potential then there can be no bound state and the energy is positive. Only for a bound state the Schrödinger energy is negative. Therefore your choice of negative energy is inconsistent with your assumption of no potential.

Answer (score 2):

The properties of a physical system depends on  *the boundary condition* as well as the governing equations. All eigen vlaues are results from a giving boundary condition.

Therefore, it is to be kept in mind that a bound state is sujected to the boundary condition:
$$
    \lim_{r\to\infty} \Psi(\vec{r}) = 0.
$$

Without this condition, the wavefuncion would not be able to be normalized. An oscilatory tail (without decaying) is certainly not allowed for bound state.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking how it is possible for there to be a bound state if the differential equation under consideration has to potential part to it. The above equation has a bound state when the absolute energy of electron is negative, but I do not get what that means.

Comment: Yes, nice answer. +1 from me.

Comment: @Patrick *but I do not get what that means.* It's conventional: free (,scattered, and motionless) electrons have $E=0$ but bound ones have $E<0$.

Comment: But what is it bounded by? There is no potential to bound the electron in the DE.

Comment: @Patrick Negative energy meaning is clear: 1. it is a bound state; 2. it should have a decaying exponential tail to fulfill the boundary condition at large $r$. It is negative, smaller than $V= 1/r$ is shallow bounded,

Comment: @Patrick asymptotically the electron goes from bound states to the scattered one. The latter is a free electron. Nothing to see here.

Comment: Right, the part I'm confused about is, that the premise of the DE is that there is no potential since we are considering parts far away(if negative energy means smaller than V=1/r, then energy is less than zero thus negative on an absolute scale). So the only physically sound solution would be the oscillatory one with positive energy. But the radial solution contains the asymptotic term. I'm asking about the logical jump made there.

Comment: For example, solving a tunnelling system, for $a<x<b$, the constant potential $V > E$. For this part, you write two functios: $\exp(\lambda x)$ and  $\exp(-\lambda x)$. If you are focusing only this segment $a<x<b$, these two solutions will make no sense at all, according to you logic here..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where your DE comes from. The full, radial part of the hydrogenic TISE is:

$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}r}\left(r^2\frac{{\rm d}R}{{\rm d}r}\right)+\frac{2\mu r^2}{\hbar^2}\left(E+\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\right)R-l(l+1)R=0$$
With $l=0,1,2,...$

Developed:
$$r^2\frac{{\rm d}^2R}{{\rm d}r^2}+2r\frac{{\rm d}R}{{\rm d}r}+\frac{2\mu r^2}{\hbar^2}\left(E+\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\right)R-l(l+1)R=0$$
and divided by $r^2$:
$$\frac{{\rm d}^2R}{{\rm d}r^2}+\bbox[lightblue]{\frac{2}{r}\frac{{\rm d}R}{{\rm d}r}}+\left(\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^2}\left(E+\bbox[lightblue]{\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}}\right)\bbox[lightblue]{-\frac{l\left(l+1\right)}{r^2}}\right)R=0$$
We can't solve this straight away, but for very large $r$, the highlighted terms are forced to zero because they go reciprocal with $r$.

That leaves us with an asymptotic equation:
$$\frac{{\rm d}^2R_{\infty}}{{\rm d}r^2}+\frac{2\mu E}{\hbar^2}R_{\infty}=0$$

$$R_{\infty}=c_3\exp{-\left(\sqrt{-\frac{2\mu E}{\hbar^2}}r\right)}$$

Here we've taken $E\to 0$ for $r \to +\infty$ and $E<0$ (so there is no imaginary part in the exponent).

This results in the radial solution:
$$R_{n,l}(r)=R_{\infty}(r)b_0\exp-{\left(\frac{\mu Ze^2r}{2\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2n}\right)}$$

---

Re. your DE:

$$d^2U/dr^2 = -\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$$

with $U(r)=\frac{R(r)}{r}$

solves to:

$$U(r)=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}r^2+c_1 r+c_2$$
So that

$$R(r)=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}r^3+c_1 r^2+c_2 r$$

which does not go asymptotically to $0$ for $r \to +\infty$.

Comment: sorry I meant to say U=R/r which reduces the messy radial term of laplacian to a single term which I've fixed. But my question was that when the DE is solved, there is no information about the potential that became negligible in it. So how is it giving a bound state solution? The DE describes a free electron so how is it possible that we give it negative energy?

Comment: *So how is it giving a bound state solution? The DE describes a free electron so how is it possible that we give it negative energy?* Because the asymptotic solution is an approximation, useful for large $r$ but oxymoronic for $r=+\infty$.

Comment: BTW, have you tried developing the DE with $U=R/r$? Where does it lead to?